# Saving in workbook not in directory as xlsx

Tags: vba, excel

The below `vba` saves the parsed output in the workbook not in the `myDir` directory as an `xlsx` and I can not seem to figure it out.  It seems to function except for that and I need some expert help figuring the last part out.  Basically, each `txt` file in the `myDir` is parsed and then the `txt` file is replaced with the parsed `xlsx`. Currently, what is happening is the first `txt` file in `myDir` is being parsed and saved in the workbook then the `vba` exits.

edit
the vba below runs but displays the parsed output in the sheet of the workbook and not saved as an xlsx in the myDir.

```
`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(fn, ".txt", ""), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook' 
stepping-through the vba I can see that fn has the full path and the filename but not sure why it does not save to myDir as an xlsx.
```

**VBA**

```
 Option Explicit 
 Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
 Dim myDir As String, fn As String 
 myDir = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\" 
 fn = Dir(myDir & "*.txt") 
 Do While fn <> "" 
    CreateXLSXFiles myDir & fn 
    fn = myDir 
 Loop 
 End Sub 
 Sub CreateXLSXFiles(fn As String) 
 Dim txt As String, m As Object, n As Long, myDir As String 
 Dim i As Long, x, temp, ub As Long, myList 
 myList = Array("Display Name", "Medical Record", "Date of Birth", "Order Date", _ 
"Gender", "Barcode", "Sample", "Build", "SpikeIn", "Location", "Control Gender", "Quality") 
myDir = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\" 
Sheets(1).Cells.Clear 
Sheets(1).Name = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(myDir & fn) 
On Error Resume Next 
n = FileLen(fn) 
If Err Then 
    MsgBox "Something wrong with " & fn 
    Exit Sub 
End If 
On Error GoTo 0 
n = 0 
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll 
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 
    .Global = True: .MultiLine = True 
    For i = 0 To UBound(myList) 
        .Pattern = "^#(" & myList(i) & " = (.*))" 
        If .test(txt) Then 
            n = n + 1 
            Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = _ 
            Array(.Execute(txt)(0).submatches(0), .Execute(txt)(0).submatches(1)) 
        End If 
    Next 
    .Pattern = "^[^#\r\n](.*[\r\n]+.+)+" 
    x = Split(.Execute(txt)(0), vbCrLf) 
    .Pattern = "(\t| {2,})" 
    temp = Split(.Replace(x(0), Chr(2)), Chr(2)) 
    n = n + 1 
    For i = 0 To UBound(temp) 
        Sheets(1).Cells(n, i + 1).Value = temp(i) 
    Next 
    ub = UBound(temp) 
    .Pattern = "((\t| {2,})| (?=(\d|"")))" 
    For i = 1 To UBound(x) 
        temp = Split(.Replace(x(i), Chr(2)), Chr(2)) 
        n = n + 1 
        Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Resize(, ub).Value = temp 
    Next 
End With 
Sheets(1).Copy 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(fn, ".txt", ""), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you opening the file as text file?  If so, then when you `SaveAs` you need to include the file type enum.

Comment: I just saw your edit...  it looks like you have a scope issue with MyDir.  It is scoped locally in both subs.  Add `Option Explicit` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in `myDir & fn` as a parameter to the **CreateXLSXFiles** procedure. The parameter is called `fn` in that procedure. Nowhere do you declare or assign a `myDir` variable in the **CreateXLSXFiles** procedure.

The 'best practice' might be to remove the extension altogether and allow the **FileFormat** parameter of the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) to set it through the appropriate [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx) constant. In this case, **xlOpenXMLWorkbook** (e.g. **51**) would be appropriate.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(fn, ".txt", ""), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

In short, you are trying to use a variable declared and assigned in one procedure in another procedure. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module code sheet to avoid these types of errors or use the VBE's Tools, Options, Editor, Require Variable Declaration. If you set the FileFormat and that parameter to determine the file extension, you should be good.

**Addendum:**

I hadn't given much attention to your primary calling procedure. A closer examination showed a discrete but critical flaw.

```
 Private Sub CommandButton21_Click() 
     Dim myDir As String, fn As String 

     myDir = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\" 
     fn = Dir(myDir & "*.txt") 
     Do While fn <> "" 
        CreateXLSXFiles myDir & fn 
        fn = Dir '<~~ get the next filename from DIR, not reassigned to myDir!!!
     Loop 

 End Sub
```

The way it was originally reassigning the value of **myDir** to **fn** wasn't going to get you anywhere. That should have been fairly straightforward with debugging methods revealing the new value of **fn**.

**Put All Together**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myDir As String, fn As String
    myDir = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\"
    fn = Dir(myDir & "file*.txt")
    Do While fn <> ""
       CreateXLSXFiles myDir & fn
       fn = Dir
    Loop
 End Sub

 Sub CreateXLSXFiles(fn As String)
     Dim txt As String, m As Object, n As Long, fp As String
     Dim i As Long, x, temp, ub As Long, myList

     myList = Array("Display Name", "Medical Record", "Date of Birth", _
                    "Order Date", "Gender", "Barcode", "Sample", "Build", _
                    "SpikeIn", "Location", "Control Gender", "Quality")

    fp = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\"

    With Worksheets(1)
        .Cells.Clear
        .Name = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(fn)

        'RegEx stuff going on here

        .Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fp & .Name, _
                              FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: making that change I can now see that the file is being referenced, but it is still saving to the workbook not as an `xlsx` in the directory, which is odd.  Thank you for the the great tip as well :).

Comment: My apologies; I failed to see that you needed to specify the [XlFileFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). See modification above.

Comment: I get a run-time invalid name for sheet error on `Sheets(1).Name = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(fn)`. Thank you :).  Since there and two text files in the directory `fn`=file1.txtfile2.txt, is that the problem is the `vba` not able to read the individual file correctly?

Comment: I updated the edit with the issue I am having and can not seem to solve... thank you :).

Comment: Have a look at the flaw I found in the primary procedure.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help and explanations, they are helping me as I learn VBA :).  I really appreciate it :).